# How to Fix Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, php-7.2

After upgrading to **PHP 7.2** I get a lot of Warnings

> Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

I've tried many ways to fix it but none have worked so far.  The commented lines below are my attempts. How can I fix this?

```
$bannerGroupCode = $this->getBannerGroupCode();
$data = $this->getDataByGroupCode($bannerGroupCode);
$bannerGroupData = $data['group_data'];
$template = '';
  if (count($bannerGroupData) > 0):
// if (empty($bannerGroupData)):
// if ($bannerGroupData && count($bannerGroupData) >= 0):
// if (is_array($bannerGroupData) && count($bannerGroupData) > 0):
// if (strlen($bannerGroupData) > 0):
    $prebaneff = $bannerGroupData->getPreBannerEffects();
    $bannerType = $bannerGroupData->getAnimationType();
```

Comment: Have you tried `((is_object($bannerGroupData) || is_array($bannerGroupData)) && count($bannerGroupData) > 0)` ?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function available in PHP (>=7.3) which checks if a variable is countable `is_countable`

Try it like

```
if (is_countable($bannerGroupData) && count($bannerGroupData) > 0):
    // Your code
endif;
```

If the function is not available, you can use below

```
if (($bannerGroupData instanceof Countable) || is_array($bannerGroupData)) && count($bannerGroupData) > 0):
    // Your code
endif;
```

Comment: The first suggestion gives the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_countable(). The second suggestion makes the banner not show.

Comment: @Freejoy Please find updated code, the first one may not work because the function is added in PHP 7.3. Please try with second code now and let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: Darn, it still doesn't work.  I get a blank screen.  I don't see any errors in the log files.  Thanks!

Comment: I found the problem with the last code. There was a missing "( " So I added the code: if ((($bannerGroupData instanceof Countable) || is_array($bannerGroupData)) && count($bannerGroupData) > 0):  and the blank screen was corrected but the banner stopped working.